# error on migrating c++/cli project from vs2010 to vs2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I let the vs2015 upgrade a project c++/cli made on vs2010 and i add the tag TargetFrameworkVersion 4.5.2 to the project as said on msdn, but still have erros (a lot) like for this :

```cpp
virtual property String^ Value
{
    String^ get()= nullptr;
}
```

I get sayntax error : nullptr.
is there Anyone  who know why upgrade does work in my case ?

Comment: C++11 happened, it adopted the `nullptr` keyword.  So sure, this is not going to compile like it used to.  Very strange syntax choice btw, this only ever compiled by accident.  You'll have to do this the right way, it is ` = 0` or `abstract` to make the property getter abstract.  Also, it is `genius`, not genuis.

Comment: Actually it compiles always perfectlly on vs2010 cause it's a string. but this was just an example of errors due to migration. I want to migrate smoothly without a lot of pain (correct each error), there are a lot of lines of code there. 
Genuis is not english (i m sorry for that ;) )